# What would stop megafauna from evolving in low gravity planets?

Tags: xenobiology, environment, fauna, gravity

On planets with lower gravity than earth what might make carbon bases megafaun rarer than in our own planet?

The planets have a source of geothermic energy, solar energy, winds and oceans.

Sometimes the oceans are ammonia and sometimes water.

Taking this into consideration, what **general** reasons might stop or discourage megafauna from evolving?

Answer (score 8):

Rapid environmental changes

Large animals grow and reproduce slowly. If your environment is subject to relatively frequent changes, it could create evolutionary pressure for creatures that grow quickly and adapt/evolve in a shorter time frame.

Comment: I dunno. didn't those giant dragonflies still produce hundreds of eggs?

Comment: @tuskiomi Is that speculation? Or was evidence actually found for that?

Answer (score 5):

An atmosphere with low oxygen, or a low density.

[Supplying the body with oxygen takes more effort for large animals](https://socratic.org/questions/why-must-larger-animals-have-an-efficient-respiratory-system)

Answer (score 2):

An evolutionary path different to the one fauna on earth took.

Afaik, earth's trees came way after bushes, grasses and other growths. If plants never developed high-strength fibre "architecture", they would not be able to grow tall the way we knew it.

If there were no selective advantage to grow tall, why would a plant develop that trait? This would probably rule out sustenance from starlight though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Mr. Canseco, keep in mind that on Earth, helium and hydrogen are not gravitationally bound. Even water vapor can escape ([http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=2#:~:text=Yes%2C%20water%20does%20escape%20into%20space%20--%20there,thermal%20energies%20can%20exceed%20escape%20velocity%20relatively%20easily.](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=2#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20water%20does%20escape%20into%20space%20--%20there,thermal%20energies%20can%20exceed%20escape%20velocity%20relatively%20easily.)). On a low-gravity planet, gasses essential to your fauna may do the same, depending on how you set it up.